# Set "Allow management of content types?" set to "Yes" within a Content Type or List Definition

Tags: content-type, list-definition, xml

How do you set "Allow management of content types?" to "Yes" within a Content Type or List Definition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done either by setting `EnableContentType=true` in the list definition or in the feature activation event we can set the attribute. Please refer the below links. They will definitely help you in solving your problem.

[Enable managing content types by default at list creation](http://snahta.blogspot.com/2009/02/enable-managing-content-types-by.html)

[Creating SharePoint 2010 List Definitions in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276355.aspx)

[A Quicker Way to Create Custom SharePoint List Templates](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/02/08/A-Quicker-Way-to-Create-Custom-SharePoint-List-Templates.aspx)

Comment: Great help! Tank you! Best regards, Tim

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sharepoint2010setup/thread/5961C35B-52FA-4121-8A3C-46A3194B8492) says to "toggle the SPList ContentTypesEnabled property from False to True".

> Just toggle the SPList ContentTypesEnabled property from False to
>   True.  That enables the use of multiple content types on the list.

Answer (score 2):

`EnableContentTypes="TRUE"` instead of `EnableContentType="TRUE"` (note the s)

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Library Settings>Advanced settings**, then set **Allow management of content types?** to yes.

Comment: Would you please brief out your answer. One liner sometimes do not help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is I set the ListCreationInfo and then create the list and enable ContentTypes:

`ListCreationInformation creationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
 creationInfo.Title = ListManager.ListTitle;
 creationInfo.TemplateType = (int)ListtemplateType.Annoucements;`

`List list = web.Lists.Add(creationInfo);
 list.Description = ListManager.ListDescription;
 list.ContentTypesEnabled = true;`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but may benefit from the PnP Powershell commands available now:

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://<tenantName>.sharepoint.com"
$ListName = "<ListName>"

#Connect to PNP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

#Enable Content Type
Set-PnPList -Identity $ListName -EnableContentTypes $True
```

Gleaned from https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/01/sharepoint-online-enable-content-types-using-powershell.html