# missing content type name and description in the new item dropdown

Tags: 2010, content-type, list-definition

I have created a content type based on the oob item content type, list definition and a list instance and they are activated via a web scoped feature.  It all works as expected apart from one thing.

The content type name and description are not displayed in the new item menu.  It prints the default "Add new item" text, but i want it to use the content type name and description.  I thought this would happen automatically but that doesnt seem the case.  Am i missing something in my list defintion / instance or content type definition?

As a note clicking the "Add new item" option does bring up the form based on the correct custom content type

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18295/set-allow-management-of-content-types-set-to-yes-within-a-content-type-or-l) but I'll summarize:  set the `EnableContentType=true` on the List element in your list definition.